# "A job that is near home" or "A job that is nearby home."

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

I was confused by these two words "near" and "nearby". In both terms---"A job that is near home" and "A job that is nearby home." , I guess, they should be ok gramatically? But I have no idea with the differences on usages and meanings between these two words.

Comment: Use *near* as a preposition – “A job that is near home.” is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"Nearby" is **much** less common as a preposition than as an adjective or adverb.

Asking GloWbE (the Global corpus of Web-based English), it reports 33000 instances of "Nearby" as an adverb, 19000 as an adjective and 0 as a preposition.  This must be partly a misclassification, because it has about 740 instances of "nearby" + an article, most of which must be using it as a preposition (against 77000 instances of "near" + an article).

So "nearby home" is possible, but much less common than "near home".

[GloWbE actually has 70 instances of "nearby home", against 194 of "near home"; but the great majority of those have "nearby" as an adjective modifying "home", as in "a nearby home". On a quick look, I didn't see a single example where "nearby" was a preposition governing "home"].

Comment: *nearby* as a preposition can take a complement, though the most common ones are without a complement. The use of *nearby* as a preposition that takes a complement is comparatively new (that is what OED says in its current version). But I have checked OED updated in 2009 that said such usage of *nearby* as a preposition with a complement is rather old-fashioned. So my wild guess is that it was a common usage at older times, and then it lost its popularity, and then again recently it started to gain ground.

Comment: I hardly use GloWbE and when I used it today for this query I couldn't find the result with time mentioned against each hits. So from there it's hard to make any guess (but we have OED result at hand, we can draw conclusion from it, though). But there also I found prepositional use of *nearby* that takes complement. For example this - *Guests also enjoy dining options both within and **nearby** the resort*. Another one - *Luckily it is rather easy to find a cheap center hotel in Rome **nearby** the Termini Station and the adjoining Repubblica Square.*

Comment: GloWbE does not tag entries for date. But the database was collected 2012-13

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Though there shouldn't be much confusion about the time when that usage got popularity and when it's out of common usage. OED clearly talks about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> A job that is **nearby**.

but near to where (your home) has to be stated somewhere else. *nearby* is an adverb. Since it modifies the verb, nothing else is needed.

> A job that is **near** (to my) home.

*near* is used as an adjective. Now it is easy to add a prepositional phrase for the reference location.
*to* or *to my* is often omitted in regular usage.